# Vimscript, how to shorten a filename?

Tags: vimscript

Given these file names, I want to get the corresponding value:

```
Chart.js          => C.j
chart.js          => c.j
chart-type.js     => ct.j
ChartType.js      => CT.j
_chart-type.scss  => ct.s
```

Here is my vimscript which only returns the first letter.
As you can see my main motivation is to shorten names in airline tabline extension.

```
function! airline#extensions#tabline#formatters#default#format(bufnr, buffers)
      return strpart(fnamemodify(bufname(a:bufnr), ':t'), 0, 1)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this code (written in `/tmp/vim.vim`):

```
fu! Shorten_filename() abort
    let bufname = fnamemodify(bufname('%'), ':t')
    let tokens = split(bufname, '\ze\u\|[-_]')
    call map(tokens, {i,v -> matchstr(v, '\a')})
    let ext = fnamemodify(bufname, ':e')
    return join(tokens, '').(!empty(ext) ? '.'.ext[0] : '')
endfu

set laststatus=2
set stl+=%{Shorten_filename()}
```

Then started Vim like this:

```
vim -Nu /tmp/vim.vim Chart.js chart.js chart-type.js ChartType.js _chart-type.scss
```

And executed `:next` to review each buffer in the argument list. The statusline displayed successively:

- `C.j`
- `c.j`
- `ct.j`
- `CT.j`
- `ct.s`

So, I guess you could try it as a base for your script. Maybe something like:

```
function! airline#extensions#tabline#formatters#default#format(bufnr, buffers)
    let bufname = fnamemodify(bufname(a:bufnr), ':t')
    let tokens = split(bufname, '\ze\u\|[-_]')
    call map(tokens, {i,v -> matchstr(v, '\a')})
    let ext = fnamemodify(bufname, ':e')
    return join(tokens, '').(!empty(ext) ? '.'.ext[0] : '')
endfunction
```

Comment: That's awesome! You just made my day :-)

Comment: nitpick: I think you can leave out the `\zs` (which looks funny anyhow)